# Okta OpenID OAuth Integration

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, openid, okta, okta-api

With reference from this URI:

http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/oidc.html#parameter-details

I have tried using the `/authorize` endpoint but I am not getting a token back in the result from Okta, I always get the result as:

> 404 - Page Not Found
>
> **The page you are looking for can't be found. Please go to your applications page and try again.**

Can anyone help me on this? Sent email to Okta developer but I'm not getting a reply.

```
var url = "https://xxx-admin.okta.com/oauth2/v1/authorize";
//string urlParams =
//    string.Format("response_type={0}&client_id={1}&redirect_uri={2}&scope={3},state={4},nonce={5}", "code",
//        "xxxxxx", redirecturl, "email", "email", );

var urlParameters =
    $"?idp={"okta"}&response_type={"id_token"}&client_id={"xxxxx"}&redirect_uri={redirecturl}" +
    $"&scope={"openid profile email address"}&response_mode={"form_post"}&state={"email"}&nonce={"nonce"}";

string redirecturl = "http://localhost/";
//grant_type,code,refresh_token,scope,redirect_uri,client_id,client_secret
var urlParameters = $"?grant_type={"password"}&code={""}&refresh_token={""}&redirect_uri={redirecturl}&" +
    $"client_id=xxxxx&client_secret=yyyyyy";
var url = "https://xxxx-admin.okta.com/oauth2/v1/token";
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url+ urlParameters);

req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
var strRequest= string.Empty;
StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
streamIn.Close();
return strResponse.ToString();
```

Comment: Have you added the redirect_uri to your allowed list of redirects?
https://xxx-admin.okta.com/admin/app/oidc_client/instance/{app}/#tab-general
Also in my experience, it didn't allow localhost -- I instead used my computer name.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but there is a public tool that has working examples of an OIDC authentication with Okta. Here is a direct link: https://oktaproxy.com/oidcgenerator.php

Comment: localhost will work, http requests will work as well. You do need to make sure you add the redirect_uri on the general tab for the application. You can all multiple for an OIDC Application

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're doing a POST for your method. I think it should be a GET.